# Element rotation and resizing in IE (jQuery UI + CSS)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, filter

I've got a script that performs rotation in all modern browsers using jQuery UI and CSS transform property. But I doesn't work in IE. I've managed to make it rotates as expected (around it's center) but I fails when I resize it again.

You can find an example in here http://vremenno.net/examples/jquery-ui-rotation/

If someone could make the same thing for IE (resizing, rotating and dragging) using this (jQuery UI + filter for IE) or another way (raphael js, canvas, etc.) I could also pay for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.useragentman.com/tests/cssSandpaper/rotateTest.html

Answer (score 1):

Just pointing in the right direction for IE

have a look at microsoft's [Matrix Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533014%28VS.85%29.aspx)

They have examples and an actual demo page explaining how to do it..

But it would probably take some tackling to integrated it with the jQuery plugins..

Also look at this jquery plugin, [jQuery 2D Transformation Plugin](http://github.com/heygrady/transform/wiki)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've tried both Matrix Filter (there is no other way) and this jQuery plugin. The problem is when element width and height are contant (i.e. there is no resize in rotated position) everything works correct but when the element is rotated and I start to resize it its proportions become different from original.